# snowflake replace string with multiple pattern on large data set

Tags: function, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with comments column which is string and I wanted to replace certain words with XXXX and the words are stored in a separate table or consider it has been stored in an Array. There is no relation between TABLE_A and EMPLOYEE.

I have came up with UDF to do the same but that is getting timed due to snowflake limit with UDF as I'm scanning against large data set.

```
Table A
ID    TEXT
001   John had completed UAT. Awaiting response from Dave Fowler.
002   Additional amount to cover invoice
003   Rewards for 25 engineers in Q3 2021
004   Memory and hard drives for Quincy has been delivered.
005   Roy A Jason is working on the defect fix.
```

Expected result. That I wanted to mask certain names and those names would be available in different table.

```
Table A
ID    TEXT
001   XXXXX had completed UAT. Awaiting response from XXXXX XXXXX.
002   Additional amount to cover invoice
003   Rewards for 25 engineers in Q3 2021
004   Memory and hard drives for XXXXX has been delivered.
005   XXXXX A XXXXX is working on the defect fix.
```

The names to be masked are available in different table and I want to read them dynamically and replace them in TEXT field from TABLE A. Probably a transient table cab loaded with masked data.

```
EMPLOYEE
ID      FULL_NAME       FIRST_NAME      MIDDLE_NAME     LAST_NAME       STATUS
A001    John Walker     John                            Walker          Active
A002    Steve Smith     Steve                           Smith           Active
A003    Jerome R Mike   Jerome          R               Mike            Inactive
A004    Mike Ford       Mike                            Ford            Active
A005    Roy A Jason     Roy             A               Jason           Inactive
A006    Dave Fowler     Dave                            Fowler          Active
A007    Quincy Jackson  Quincy                          Jackson         Inactive
```

Have created  an UDF to have 2 input parameters FULL_NAME from employee table as array and Text field from Table A

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UDF_MASK_PII_DATA(TEXT_VAL VARCHAR,NAME_LIST ARRAY)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE javascript
AS 
$$
    var txt_val = TEXT_VAL;
    var mask_name_list = NAME_LIST;
    
    //For loop to iterate over FULL_NAME from array input
    for ( var i = 0; i < mask_name_list.length; i++ ){
    
        var name = mask_name_list[i].trim().replace(/['()]/g,'');
    
        //var re = new RegExp(name, 'gi');
        //var txt_val = txt_val.replace(re,'XXXXX');
        
        //Spliting each name with WHITESPACE and COMMA
        var split_name = name.split(/[\s,]+/);
        
        //Looping over FULL_NAME to check against text field and replacing them with XXXXX
        for ( var j = 0; j < split_name.length; j++ ){
            //Below IF statement to skipp any part of name which is equal to single character like Middle Names
            if ( split_name[j].length > 1 ) {
                var re = new RegExp(split_name[j], 'gi');
                var txt_val = txt_val.replace(re,'XXXXX');
            }
        }
    }

    return txt_val;

$$;
```

Below to query to check actual text and masked text. Since I'm trying to scan large data set from Table_A and EMPLOYEE table UDF timesout. Is there any optimal solution to get the expected result.  It would be great if someone throw some light on this to get done.

```
select
    ID,
    TEXT,
    UDF_MASK_PII_DATA(TEXT, (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(distinct FULL_NAME) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY FULL_NAME ASC) AS NAME_LIST FROM EMPLOYEE)) as MASKED_TEXT
    
from TABLE_A;
```

Comment: Can you  remove all trimming,spaces .. etc  code from  UDF and try to perform outside of  script using snowflake in built functions regexp_replace .. and try to pass cleaner data to UDF to see some improvement.

Comment: @Anand, Thanks for the suggestion. Even that doesn't helps but somewhat better performance now. ` with CTE as (
  select distinct split(listagg(NAME_LIST_1,','),',') NAME_LIST
  from (select 
    distinct c.value::string as NAME_LIST_1
   from
    (select 
     distinct REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(trim(upper(name)),'[()]',''),' ',',') as NAME_LIST 
    from EMPLOYEE)
    , lateral flatten(input=>split(NAME_LIST, ',')) c
   )
  where length(NAME_LIST_1) > 2
 )
 select ID,TEXT,
  UDF_MASK_PII_DATA(TEXT,(select NAME_LIST from CTE)) as MASKED_TEXT
 from TABLE_A ;--limit 100;`

Comment: One more try you would give a try moving away Java script into Snowflake scripting as STORED proc because you are trying to replace data with "XXX'  based on  another table data and same logic what you wrote can doable with Snowflake functions and scripts. Also I thought of simulate same but I dont have huge dataset to run and test.

Comment: @Anand, Can you please help with any ideal way to achieve this through Stored procedure. I was thinking about this but couldn't get any idea/logic to get this implemented while loading data from one table to other .